# Правильно ли постоянно инициализировать новый объект для EventHandler?

Tags: c#, события

Имеется такой код (обертка) для MediaElement'a, и вот, когда заметил множество новых инициализаций класса EventHandler'a задумался, а правильно ли это? Собственно сам код ниже. Есть ли другой способ сделать тоже самое, при этом не создавая каждый раз новый EventHandler?

```
namespace Mynamespace.Controls
{
    public class AnimePlayer : Border
    {
        public delegate void StateChangedEventHandler(object sender, AnimePlayerEventArgs animePlayerEventArgs);

        private readonly IMessageService _messageService;

        public AnimePlayer(IMessageService messageService)
            : this(
                messageService,
                new MediaElement {LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual, UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual})
        {
        }

        public AnimePlayer(IMessageService messageService, MediaElement mediaElement)
        {
            _messageService = messageService;
            MediaElement = mediaElement;
            CreateControl();
        }

        private MediaElement MediaElement { get; }

        public event StateChangedEventHandler PlayerStateChanged;

        private void CreateControl()
        {
            Background = Brushes.Black;
            Child = new Grid
            {
                RowDefinitions = {new RowDefinition(), new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto}},
                ColumnDefinitions = {new ColumnDefinition(), new ColumnDefinition()},
                Children = {MediaElement}
            };
            MediaElement.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            MediaElement.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(MediaElement, 2);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(MediaElement, 2);
            MediaElement.MediaFailed +=
                async (sender, args) => await _messageService.ShowErrorAsync(args.ErrorException);
            MediaElement.MediaOpened +=
                (sender, args) => OnPlayerStateChanged(new AnimePlayerEventArgs(PlayerState.Playing));
            MediaElement.BufferingStarted +=
                (sender, args) =>
                {
                    OnPlayerStateChanged(new AnimePlayerEventArgs(PlayerState.Buffering, MediaElement.BufferingProgress));
                };
            MediaElement.MediaEnded +=
                (sender, args) =>
                {
                    OnPlayerStateChanged(new AnimePlayerEventArgs(PlayerState.Stopped));
                    MediaElement.Stop();
                    MediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
                };
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            if (!MediaElement.HasAudio && !MediaElement.HasVideo && MediaElement.Source == null) return;
            OnPlayerStateChanged(new AnimePlayerEventArgs(PlayerState.Playing));
            MediaElement.Play();
        }

        public void Play(Uri mediaUri)
        {
            OpenMedia(mediaUri);
            Play();
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            if (!MediaElement.HasAudio && !MediaElement.HasVideo && MediaElement.Source == null) return;
            OnPlayerStateChanged(new AnimePlayerEventArgs(PlayerState.Paused));
            MediaElement.Pause();
        }

        public void OpenMedia(Uri mediaUri)
        {
            MediaElement.Source = mediaUri;
        }

        public void OpenMedia(Uri mediaUri, bool playOnOpen)
        {
            if (playOnOpen)
            {
                Play(mediaUri);
                return;
            }
            OpenMedia(mediaUri);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            MediaElement.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Происходит при изменении StateNow
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="animeplayereventargs"></param>
        protected virtual void OnPlayerStateChanged(AnimePlayerEventArgs animeplayereventargs)
        {
            PlayerStateChanged?.Invoke(this, animeplayereventargs);
        }

        public class AnimePlayerEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public AnimePlayerEventArgs()
            {
            }

            public AnimePlayerEventArgs(PlayerState playerState)
            {
                StateNow = playerState;
            }

            public AnimePlayerEventArgs(PlayerState playerState, double progressBuffering) : this(playerState)
            {
                BufferingProgress = progressBuffering;
            }
            /// <summary>
            ///     Что делает проигрыватель
            /// </summary>
            public PlayerState StateNow { get; internal set; }

            public double BufferingProgress { get; internal set; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Состояние аниме проигрывателя
    /// </summary>
    public enum PlayerState
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Проигрывает
        /// </summary>
        Playing,

        /// <summary>
        ///     Приостоновлен
        /// </summary>
        Paused,

        /// <summary>
        ///     Бефферизация
        /// </summary>
        Buffering,

        /// <summary>
        ///     Медиа закрыто, простаивает
        /// </summary>
        Closed,

        /// <summary>
        ///     Остановлен
        /// </summary>
        Stopped,

        /// <summary>
        ///     Открытие мультимедиа
        /// </summary>
        MediaOpen
    }
}
```

Comment: Где вы видите *"множество новых экземпляров класса EventHandler'a"*?

Comment: Имеется ввиду множество инициализаций, хотелось бы от этого избавиться.

Comment: Я тоже их не сумел найти в коде. Не могли бы вы сформулировать вопрос конкретней?

Comment: @Uranus Сама суть вопроса в заголовке, имеется ввиду множество инициализаций, хотелось бы от этого избавиться, на ум приходила мысль о статике, но будет ли толк?

Comment: Просто единственный класс экземпляры которого создает и инициализирует приведенный в вопросе код в количествах подходящих под формулировку "постоянно" и "множество" - это AnimePlayerEventArgs. Если вы о нем, то так делать правильно.